# How can I use sync task await to test downloading?

Tags: c#, winforms

In form1 button click event :

First I'm trying to generate the Radar links.

```
private async void btnStart_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            lblStatus.Text = "Downloading...";

            await rad.GetRadarImages();

            await sat.DownloadSatelliteAsync();
            foreach(string link in sat.SatelliteUrls())
            {
                urls.Add(link);
            }
            await DownloadAsync();
        }
```

The Radar class :

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace Extract
{
    class Radar
    {
        private List<string> links = new List<string>();
        string defaultlink;
        DateTime current;
        string currentLink;
        public List<DateTime> dates = new List<DateTime>();
        DateTime workingFirstDateTime;

        public async Task GetRadarImages()
        {
            defaultlink = "mysite.com/Radar_";

            current = RoundDown(DateTime.Now, TimeSpan.FromMinutes(-5));

            var ct = current.ToString("yyyyMMddHHmm");
            currentLink = defaultlink + ct + ".gif";

            using (System.Net.WebClient wc = new System.Net.WebClient())
            {

                wc.DownloadFileCompleted += (s, e) =>
                {
                    if (e.Error != null)
                    {       
                            current = current.AddMinutes(-5);
                            ct = current.ToString("yyyyMMddHHmm");
                            currentLink = defaultlink + ct + ".gif";
                            wc.DownloadFileTaskAsync(new Uri(currentLink), @"d:\Downloaded Images\Radar\radar0.gif");
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        workingFirstDateTime = current;

                        GenerateRadarLinks();
                    }
                };

                await wc.DownloadFileTaskAsync(new Uri(currentLink), @"d:\Downloaded Images\Radar\radar0.gif");
            }
        }

        private void GenerateRadarLinks()
        {
            for (var i = 0; i < 34; i++)
            {
                current = current.AddMinutes(-5);

                dates.Add(current);
                var date = dates[i].ToString("yyyyMMddHHmm");
                links.Add(defaultlink + date + ".gif");
            }

            dates.Insert(0, workingFirstDateTime);
        }

        DateTime RoundDown(DateTime date, TimeSpan interval)
        {
            return new DateTime(date.Ticks / interval.Ticks *
                interval.Ticks);
        }
    }
}
```

I'm downloading the first time :

```
await wc.DownloadFileTaskAsync(new Uri(currentLink), @"d:\Downloaded Images\Radar\radar0.gif");
```

Then in the completed event I'm checking if the downloaded file was fine or not by checking for error/s :

```
if (e.Error != null)
                        {       
                                current = current.AddMinutes(-5);
                                ct = current.ToString("yyyyMMddHHmm");
                                currentLink = defaultlink + ct + ".gif";
                                wc.DownloadFileTaskAsync(new Uri(currentLink), @"d:\Downloaded Images\Radar\radar0.gif");
                        }
                        else
                        {
                            workingFirstDateTime = current;
    
                            GenerateRadarLinks();
                        }
                    };
```

If there is an error rebuild the link and try to download again this way I'm trying to rebuild the link over and over trying to download it until the download is success if there is no error/s the download is success then generate the link by calling the method GenerateRadarLinks()

The problem is I used a breakpoint on the line :

```
if (e.Error != null)
```

I see error 404 not found so the link is incorrect it should try to download over again with the new built link but instead it's jumping to the Program.cs and throw there the exception 404 not found :

[image: Not trying over and over again to download but throwing the exception in Program.cs]

Why it's not trying to download the new built link over and over again until success ?

Comment: Looks like you should take a look at an [introduction to exception handling](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/fundamentals/exceptions/exception-handling)

Comment: @Xerillio I thought checking if error is null or not is the same like try and catch.  how can I use try and catch in this case in the completed event ?

Comment: You are awaiting the download task, this should also raise a WebException when the download fails. If you wouldn't await it, you wouldn't get an exception after the DownloadFileCompleted event gets raised. I'd suggest to remove the event handler and use try/catch in a loop. Even better, also switch to the [HttpClient class](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.net.http.httpclient?view=net-5.0#methods). It has a better async support, also allowing cancellation by CancellationTokens.